# Qt - Return an Array Of Array Of qint32

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this in my main :

```
void main()
{
     qint32 LED[32][32];
     LED = INIT_ALL(LED);
}
```

i have this, but it don't work :

```
qint32** INIT_ALL(qint32 LED[32][32])
{
     //SET TO ZERO
     return LED;
}
```

I would like return correctly this LED.

Comment: didn't you get any error on compilation or atleast a warning

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass LED by pointer (or reference in case of C++) to INIT_ALL. Otherwise, a copy will be passed to the subroutine, which is not, what you want.
BTW, you should start with learning C or C++ before starting with Qt. You definitely need basic knowledge of the programming language before starting with Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Code should throw a warning if not an error, try passing reference, well actually you are passing reference anyway check this snippet and see if it makes sense

```
void INIT_ALL( int ar[][32]) // No return, we are passing reference 
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < 32 ; i ++ )
        for ( j = 0 ; j < 32; j ++ )
            ar[i][j] = 0;

}
```

Somewhere in your code

```
   int a[32][32] ;

    INIT_ALL(a);

    // use LED as it is
```